# valueNotFound: Cannot get keyed decoding container found null instead

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My project includes dynamic data, that changes when controllers change etc, so at one point my data may be:

```
[
   {
      "callDescription":"TEST 16/12",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":0,
      "callMade":false,
      "callMade_dateTime":"false_1608151560.0",
      "dateTime":1608044666,
      "type":"Breakfast Call"
   },
     {
      "callDescription":"TEST 16/12",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":0,
      "callMade":false,
      "callMade_dateTime":"false_1608151560.0",
      "dateTime":1608044666,
      "type":"Breakfast Call"
   },
]
```

Then a piece of code is ran and my data is now

```
[
   {
      "callDescription":"TEST 16/12",
      "callDuration":"5-8 Minutes",
      "callID":0,
      "callMade":false,
      "callMade_dateTime":"false_1608151560.0",
      "dateTime":1608044666,
      "type":"Breakfast Call"
   },
     null
]
```

Which is causing the valueNotFound error when the data is requested again.

What is the best way to skip/handle any indexes that are null?

Here is my API code:

```
class Service {
    static let shared = Service()
    let BASE_URL = "https://url.com"
    
    func fetchClient(completion: @escaping ([Calls]) -> ()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        // handle error
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to fetch data with error: ", error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let myDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let calls = try myDecoder.decode([Calls].self, from: data)
            completion(calls)
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to create JSON with error: ", error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

`Calls` model:

```
struct Calls: Decodable  {
    let callDescription, callDuration, callMade_dateTime: String
    let callID: Int
    let dateTime: Date
    let callMade: Bool
    let type: String
}
```

Comment: You have a dictionary and not an array. I don't know what Calls is but perhaps you can use `.decode([String: Calls].self,...`

Comment: Have updated q to include my model. `String: Calls` wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I don’t see how that type (Calls) could match the json in your question

Comment: I don't understand how your decoding would work as such with the sample JSON. It doesn't make sense. You are skipping/hiding too much info and that's harder for us to tell what's wrong.

Comment: The JSON is just an example, the model etc all works fine at decoding the data, so I guess the real question is how to handle `null` when they occur to prevent an error? Can I just skip null indexes in an array? @JoakimDanielson @Larme

Comment: `decodeIfPresent()`? And the fact that your JSON is a Dictionary, and not a Array, that's strange. Even more with "string key" as "index".

Comment: @Larme Sorry I am not familiar with that function, is that part of the `JSONDecoder` class? Thanks for your responses thus far.

Comment: @Larme I have updated my code to include my actual data, I only omitted it because I thought it'd save time. I guess not.

Comment: Create a understandable example, but I think that `[Calls].self`should be `[Calls?].self`. Then if you don't want optionals, just `flatMap()`  on the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
let calls = try myDecoder.decode([Calls].self, from: data)
completion(calls)
```

=>

```
let calls = try myDecoder.decode([Calls?].self, from: data)
completion(calls.compactMap{ $0 })
```

Let's simplify the example (I started writing the answer before you wrote a real JSON working) :

```
struct Custom: Codable {
    let data: String
}

let jsonString = """
[{"data": "Hello"}, {"data": "world"}]
"""

let jsonString2 = """
    [{"data": "Hello"}, null, {"data": "world"}]
"""
```

So, some values might be null inside your JSON. That's where we can use Optional.

```
func test(json: String) {
    do {
        print("Testing with [Custom].self: \(json)")
        let customs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Custom].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        print("Result: \(customs)")
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

func test2(json: String) {
    do {
        print("Testing with [Custom?].self: \(json)")
        let customs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Custom?].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        print("Result with optionals: \(customs)")
        let unwrapped = customs.compactMap { $0 }
        print("Result unwrapped: \(unwrapped)")
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

```
test(json: jsonString)
test(json: jsonString2)
test2(json: jsonString)
test2(json: jsonString2)
```

Output:

```
$>Testing with [Custom].self: [{"data": "Hello"}, {"data": "world"}]
$>Result: [Custom(data: "Hello"), .Custom(data: "world")]
$>Testing with [Custom].self: [{"data": "Hello"}, null, {"data": "world"}]
$>Error: valueNotFound(Swift.KeyedDecodingContainer<.Custom.CodingKeys>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1)], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil))
$>Testing with [Custom?].self: [{"data": "Hello"}, {"data": "world"}]
$>Result with optionals: [Optional(.Custom(data: "Hello")), Optional(.Custom(data: "world"))]
$>Result unwrapped: [.Custom(data: "Hello"), .Custom(data: "world")]
$>Testing with [Custom?].self: [{"data": "Hello"}, null, {"data": "world"}]
$>Result with optionals: [Optional(.Custom(data: "Hello")), nil, Optional(.Custom(data: "world"))]
$>Result unwrapped: [.Custom(data: "Hello"), .Custom(data: "world")]
```